# mysql count total

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
general
+----+------+
| ID | hits |
+----+------+
| 1  |  10  |
+----+------+
| 2  |  6   |
+----+------+
| 3  |  31  |
+----+------+
```

How I can get the total of hits?

Comment: Im starting with mysql and don't know all the methods, I've tried getting an array and then sum, but clearly isn't the best way. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @greenbandit: The manual contains a list of all the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html). There are only a handful so it shouldn't take long to skim through them and get familiar with what's available. You'll save a lot of time in the long run by spending a little time now reading the manual.

Comment: Isn't it a civic duty to +1, if other answer is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function to get the total of a column:

```
SELECT SUM(hits) FROM general
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(hits) FROM general;
```